# How can I get a drawn Object from a map leaflet draw using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, leaflet.draw, ui-leaflet

I am using angular leaflet, leaflet-draw and I am trying to get a circle (or other drawn object) object to see if a point on the map appears within it overtime.  I need to use it in a separate service.  How can I access the data for an object already drawn somewhere else in my angular code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.  To access a drawn object in the way I was attempting, I had persisted the `L.FeatureGroup` object in my service.  Inside this object is a `layersDrawnItems` sub-object.  This object has a `_layers` array which contains the list of drawn objects.

They can then be accessed using the leaflet API.  I still don't know how I was supposed to find this with the given documentation (unless I missed something completely obvious, which I am assuming I did, given that this would seem to be basic functionality) but if anyone else needs to know, here it is.